# Can't solve my camera

Tags: error, tracking

I was tryng to track my scene. I made and image sequence then exported all the jpg pictures. To get tracing points I used the "Detect Features" option to create keyframes. When I was ready I pushed the button "Solve Camera Motion" And it displayed that:

Atleast 8 trackers...
[image]

Can someone help me find out why it says that and could help me fix it?

Video: https://youtu.be/xEaocgkWAVM

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to solve a shot like that with the default solver. The camera is stationary and is rotating only, in those cases you need to solve as **tripod**. Be aware that this will only reconstruct the rotation of the camera, but will not yield any 3D information.

Read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Comment: Yeah, but I didnt shoot it on a tripod. It was shot handheld

Comment: It doesn't matter, **there is no parallax information on the shot**, It can only be solved as tripod.